# Workflow for Component giving an Error- "Operation is not supported on a new item or on a null URI."

Tags: tridion

i have created a component which is using a schema in which the DEFAULT WORKFLOW- "Content Approval Process " has been applied.But now if the component is created it goes to specified user and when that user finishes the activity it gives the ERROR-"Operation is not supported on a new item or on a null URI." Can somebody Please Explain how to resolve this issue.?

Comment: i am using sdl tridion 2011 sp1 . Workflow is like this:-first the content author create content(Manual Activity) and then it goes to chief editor(Manual Decision) for review.Based on his decision,it is either sent back to the author using automatic activity or for ready to publish approval state.

Comment: Are you getting the error at the first activity, or at one of the automatic activities?

Comment: Is your process definition configured to store snapshots?

Comment: Jeremy , I m getting this error when i m trying to finish the first activity

Comment: As far as I'm aware this error 99% of the cases occurs when something isn't filled out. I'm not familiar with workflows, though, so I'm not sure whether there has to be anything filled out. Bear in mind that, while some fields or any inputs may not be seen as mandatory and could be left empty, need to be either checked if they are null in the template, or made mandatory. For testing purposes, first try and fill out everything that has to do with your workflow and see if the error persists.

Comment: @MDa to the schema on which this workflow has been applied contains only one text field and when i created a component using this schema i have filled this field...but the issue still persist.

Comment: This is a long shot, but does the component, page, or even the structuregroup where the component is located have some unfilled fields, or metadata?

Comment: @MDa No ,i just created a component and it went to the workflow.I can add this component to other Component,Page or Structure group only when it is approved by all the activites of the workflow.

Comment: Can you paste the code of the automated activities?  As MDa said, this error results from calling methods such as 'Publish' on items before they are saved.  I have seen it before, but not in workflow.  I assume the actions from the automated script are triggering the failure.  Also, can you check the event viewer for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to run some operation that requires a checked-in version of the component. Since it doesn't exist yet (version 1 is not yet approved) Tridion complains about it.

Post the code where the error is coming from and we may be able to help further.

[EDIT]

After re-reading, I'm pretty positive is an Event being triggered on SAVE and assuming the component's version 1 already exists. Check your event system.

Comment: i got this error:-Unable to finish the Workflow Activity (tcm:142-227-131104)
Operation is not supported on a new item or on a null URI.

Error Code:
0x80040325 (-2147220699)

Call stack:
Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String)
Tridion.ContentManager.Communicator.SendWorkflowNotification(ActivityInstance,Trustee) [line 181]
Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicatorEventHandler.OnAssignActivity(ActivityInstance,AssignActivityEventArgs,EventPhases) [line 33]
ActivityInstance.FinishActivity

Comment: also i have ckecked my event system none of events are triggering i.e current value for all the event is set to 0 in Console Root\SDL Tridion Content Manager\Event Triggers\Component

Comment: An event is clearly being triggered - the CommunicatorEventHandler is running ;) What version of Tridion are you running on?

Comment: @JeremyGrand-Scrutton:- i m using sdl tridion 2011 and could u plz help in locating this EventHandler as i haven't written any event handler for it

Comment: Check your Tridion.ContentManager.Config, "Extensions" section. Also, go read some documentation about it, it's VERY different from 2009 and earlier.